# Knowing the Child type of an abstract class

Tags: c#, oop

I'm having problems designing a service layer when using a `Table per Hierarchy` setup with entity framework. My problem is that I am getting an object of a specific type but I want to check what the type is. This is better explained in codes:

**Abstract Domain Class**

```
public abstract class Order
{
    public string OrderId { get; set; }
}
```

**The inherited class**

```
public class OrderProduct : Order
{
    public List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}

public class OrderSubscription : Order
{
    public decimal Fee { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

So you can basically do this:

```
orderRepository.GetOrders();
//OR
orderRepository.GetOrders().OfType<OrderProduct>();
//OR
orderRepository.GetOrders().OfType<OrderSubscription>();
```

I'm basically using the first one. It returns `IQueryable<Order>`

I want to make 1 service layer method that makes the call that gets any type, for eg:

```
public Order GetOrder(string orderId)
{
    return orderRepository.GetOrders().FirstOrDefault(o => o.OrderId == orderId);
}
```

**The Problem**

In my controller, how can I tell what type the object is after making the call to `GetOrder(string orderId)`? If it is of the type `OrderProduct`, then I also need the navigational property (`List<OrderDetail>`) to be there when I cast it.

One solution to this I see is to make 2 types of service layer call for each `Order` class. Call 1, and if it returns null, then call the other. But is there an OOP way to do this in C#?

Comment: off the top of my head, just add a type prop in the abstract class and in the inherited classes set it. Or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what you are asking but i think you are looking for the `is` operator:

```
Order order = //...    
bool isSubscription = order is OrderSubscription;
```

Also if you want to use the value after that you can also use `as` and this will cast it or return `null` it it's not of the type.

```
Order order = //...
OrderSubscription subscription = order as OrderSubscription;
if (subscription != null)
{
  // use subscription
}
```

Comment: So even tho I'm returning `Order`, it can still be of type `OrderSubscription` and I'm able to cast it with all of the properties thats not in the base class?

Comment: Yes. A `OrderSubscription` is also an `Order`, and an `Order` might also be `OrderSubscription`.

Comment: Casting doesn't change the real type of the object. Cast actually just tells the compiler that that this variable is supposed to of type Order, but the really object is untouched

Answer (score 0):

```
Order o = GetOrder("12345");
if (o is OrderProduct)
{
    var product = (OrderProduct)o;
}
else if (o is OrderSubscription)
{
    var subscription = (OrderSubscription)o;
}
```

Does this do what you need?  I'm slightly fuzzy on what your needs are.